# Remove margin on a label on 2 lines?

Tags: objective-c, ios, label, margin

I just have a little graphic issue, i have a label which contain a text on 2 lines but there is an horrible margin, like 10px ...

Is there an solution for removing or reducing this marging ?

have i to use web view for use css ? :/

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: What kind of margin? Could you post a print screen?

Comment: Also, can to let us know how you created this UILabel? Interface Builder? Programmatically (in which case post the code)?

Comment: I edited to add an image, so i'm using an UILabel created via a storyboard, and i want to remove the space between "eduPad" and "apps" which is in the same label but on 2 lines

Comment: Ah, now I see what you're talking about. In this case, I think making it multiple labels, one for each line, or just make the whole button an image, adjusting your spacing manually, is the way to go. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't an easy solution.
You could try some of the tips presented here: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/14178-spacing-between-lines-multiline-uilabel.html#
or break your label into two different labels or use an uiwebview.

Anyway, excepting the case where you have a localized label, with dynamic text based on an xml, just use two different labels for each line and place them as you please

Comment: Thanks i'll take a look at your link ^^